# Get the number of years between two dates with momentjs? Not full years

Tags: javascript, reactjs, momentjs

I would like to know how to get number of years that went by between two dates in momentjs, not full years.

For example, if I choose Dec 30, 2017 to Jan 02, 2020 I want the result to be 4 or an array of the 4 years that are included (2017, 2018, 2019, 2020). If I calculate full years in this example I would not get 4, because the number of milliseconds between both dates are less than 4 years.

Comment: impossible to calculate, no year can have the same number of milliseconds, we are even obliged to recalibrate the GPS every day

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `date1` and `date2` are moment objects:

```js
const diff = date2.year() - date1.year() + 1
```

To make the array you requested.

```js
const arr = [...Array(diff).keys()].map(i => i + date1.year())
```

Comment: This was great! It helped me a lot! Thanks! I tried to apply the same with months, but if I take June 2019 to August 2020 it gives me only 3 months because it only takes the month names (June, July, August). Any idea on how to have this for different time intervals (months, days)?

Comment: Please add your request to another question or update this one in order to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You can snap the starting date to the beginning of the year and loop a year at a time until you surpass the end date, pushing the year part into a result array.

```
const yearArray = (date1, date2) => {
  const arr = [];
  const date = date1.startOf('year');

  do {
    arr.push(date.year())
  } while(date.add(1, 'year') < date2);

  return arr;
};
```

```js
const date1 = moment("Dec 30, 2017", "MMM DD, YYYY");
const date2 = moment("Jan 02, 2020", "MMM DD, YYYY");

const yearArray = (date1, date2) => {
  const arr = [];
  const date = date1.startOf('year');

  do {
    arr.push(date.year())
  } while(date.add(1, 'year') < date2);

  return arr;
};

console.log(yearArray(date1, date2)); // [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```

Alternative version that removes all the date property accesses

```
const yearArray = (date1, date2) => {
  const arr = [];
  let year = date1.startOf('year').year();
  const endYear = date2.year();

  do {
    arr.push(year)
  } while(year++ < endYear);

  return arr;
};
```

```js
const date1 = moment("Dec 30, 2017", "MMM DD, YYYY");
const date2 = moment("Jan 02, 2020", "MMM DD, YYYY");

const yearArray = (date1, date2) => {
  const arr = [];
  let year = date1.startOf('year').year();
  const endYear = date2.year();

  do {
    arr.push(year)
  } while(year++ < endYear);

  return arr;
};

console.log(yearArray(date1, date2)); // [2017, 2018, 2019, 2020]
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.27.0/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
```